# How do I get the fully qualified path of a share in Windows?

Tags: windows, network-shares

I know that I can find out what a drive is mapped to with:

`net use X:`

But how do I resolve a share easily? Like `\\JoshPC\SomeSharedFolder`

Is there a way to get the fully qualified path?

Comment: It's called a UNC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to see the full path and you have admin privs on the remote workstation then the following will work

wmic /node:hostname share

Comment: I think this is what I'm after. With my example above, would that be something like "wmic \node:JoshPC SomeSharedFolder"? This doesn't work. I do have admin on the remote PC.

Comment: thats a forward slash / right  and no just type "wmic /node:joshpc share"  this will list all paths for the shares

Comment: also if you want to trim it do just a specific share you do the following  "wmic /node:joshpc where "name like '%sharename%'" get path"

Comment: wmic is a very powerful tool, if you can think it wmic can do it!
tr

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking how to see UNCs that you have browsed to but not mapped, you can do that by typing `net use` without a drive letter after it.

Also, what you listed isn't a fully qualified path. For it to be fully qualified, it would have to have the domain included in the server name.

If you are asking to see what shares a server has available, you cannot do this from a client. But you can do this on the server by using `net share` with no other parameters.

Answer (score 2):

The "wmic" command didn't work for me but I was able to see all the shares and their absolute path (Resource) by executing this on the server that contains the shares:

```
net share
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

- A share name of E$
- A machine name of MYmachine
- A domain of MYdomain.local

A cross domain fully qualified mapping to a machine share would be formatted like:

```
\\\MYmachine.MYdomain.local\E$
```

Answer (score 0):

...and rounding out the possibilities [discussed by MarkM](https://superuser.com/questions/149794/how-do-i-get-the-fully-qualified-path-of-a-share-in-windows/149795#149795): If you're trying to see where on Josh's PC the share `SomeSharedFolder` is on his hard drive, you can't do that from the client. From your perspective, the share name *is* the full path.